# Export layers in photoshop with levels applied

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export

I have the following sequence of 35 layers within Photoshop CC 2015:

[image: Photoshop layers with levels]

I'm using **Files** > **Export** > **Layers to Files** to save the images as JPEGS. Unfortunately, the levels are not being applied to each image and are being processed as empty JPEGS.

How do you export the images with levels applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Export Layers to Files you're going to have to go through and Merge Down the adjustment layers either through the layer panel or with the shortcut <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Be sure to save before and then close after so you don't ruin your working file.